# PHP Remove text filter

Tags: php, sql, database

I have a minor question about removing filtered text, and instead, executing whatever code it gives.

For example:

If I filter() some text that gets put into my database, is there a PHP code that allows me to "reverse" the filter, and show the text without having added the filter() command?

Example:

```
<?php mysql_query("INSERT INTO blah ('".filter($_POST['blah'])."')"); ?>
```

Can I display this text straight from the database without having the filter apply from when it was ADDED to the database?
Is there a string?

I have no clue, thanks for your help in advance.

:)

Comment: Yes, you can. Use prepared statements. Google for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe function preg_replace is one possibility.

Comment: Ahh, I see what that does. But doesn't that mean I have to add every letter / word that I want to have replaced when typed? Because the information I'm grabbing is coming from my database.